# amule install on ubuntu 20.4

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I tried to install amule 2.3.2 using apt-get install amule, but it doesn't work. Error 'Package 'amule' has no installation candidate'.
On Ubuntu 19.10. it workes fine without problems.
Are there any adjustments to do on 20.04?

Comment: It has been removed from Ubuntu `focal` repos. You can try to download and install it from eoan.

Comment: Does this mean that **amule** will longer be available in Ubuntu 20.04+?

Comment: possible answer in https://github.com/amule-project/amule/issues/136

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can download its packages from Ubuntu 19.10 and install them manually:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/amule
cd ~/Downloads/amule

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/amule/amule_2.3.2-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/amule/amule-common_2.3.2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets3.0/libwxgtk3.0-0v5_3.0.4+dfsg-12_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that **amule** will longer be available
> in Ubuntu 20.04+? – @FedonKadifeli May 10 at 9:49

For Ubuntu 20.10 it's already available (https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amule)

Comment: Add a new line with a repository to:  "/etc/apt/sources.list"  for example following EU mirror:    deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main universe

Answer (score 0):

... there is also a 2.4 version around and not sure if it makes a lot of difference but it does exist and seems to be the latest available for Ubuntu. It requires:

● libboost-system1.58.0_1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
● libcrypto++9v5_5.6.1-9ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
● libupnp6_1.6.24-4_amd64.deb

then
● amule-common_2.4.0_git20151120.0023527bc2-1ubuntu1_all.deb
● amule_2.4.0_git20151120.0023527bc2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

all very easy to find and then it installs fine ....